# How to setup Windows from an external hard drive?

Tags: windows, installation, external-hard-drive

Is it possible to install Windows from an external hard drive?

I have Windows XP installed on my laptop, and I want to remove it and install Windows 7.

My Windows 7 installation is in an `.iso` format on an external USB hard drive.

Is it possible to install it or will I need to put in a DVD before I start installing?

Comment: I've also installed Windows 7 from a external USB DVD drive without any problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Windows 7 without a DVD drive](https://superuser.com/questions/138056/install-windows-7-without-a-dvd-drive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the directions [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/):

> 1. Plug-in your USB flash drive to USB port and move all the contents
>      from USB drive to a safe location on your system.
> 2. Open a Command Prompt with admin rights. Type "cmd" into the Start
>      menu search box and hit
>      <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. Type `DISKPART` and hit Enter … Next type `LIST DISK` and note down
>      the Disk number (e.g. "Disk 1") of your USB flash drive.
> 4. Next type all the below commands one by one.
>
>    ```
>    SELECT DISK 1
>    CLEAN
>    CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
>    SELECT PARTITION 1
>    ACTIVE
>    FORMAT FS=NTFS
>    (Format process may take few seconds)
>    ASSIGN
>    EXIT
>    ```
>
>    Don’t close the command prompt as we need to execute one more command
>      at the next step. Just minimize it.
> 5. Next insert your Windows7/Vista DVD into the optical drive and
>      check the drive letter of the DVD drive. In this guide I will assume
>      that your DVD drive letter is “D” and USB drive letter is “H” (open my
>      computer to know about it).
> 6. Maximize the minimized Command Prompt in the 4th step.Type  the
>      following command now: D: CD BOOT and hit enter.Where “D” is your DVD
>      drive letter. CD BOOT and hit enter to see the below message.
> 7. Type another command given below to update the USB drive with
>      BOOTMGR compatible code.
>
>    ```
>    BOOTSECT.EXE /NT60 H:
>    ```
>
> Where “H” is your USB drive letter. Once you enter the above command
>   you will see the below message.
>
> 8. Copy your Windows 7/Vista DVD contents to the USB flash drive.
> 9. Your USB drive is ready to boot and install Windows 7/Vista. Only
>      thing you need to change the boot priority at the BIOS to USB from the
>      HDD or CD ROM drive. I won’t explain it as it’s just the matter the
>      changing the boot priority or enabling the USB boot option in the
>      BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external USB hard drive or flash drive.  The steps to install from a USB hard drive can be found here:

[Use a USB hard drive to make a bootable Windows 7 install](http://www.sevenforums.com/news/498-usb-hard-drive-bootable-windows-7-install-disk.html)

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS needs to support booting from a USB storage device, and the device needs to have a boot sector. If there is no boot sector then you cannot boot from the device. Unless the boot sector contains or loads code that is capable of reading a bootable ISO image, then **no**, you cannot boot an ISO image on an external storage device.