# Install Windows 7 without a DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, installation

Is it possible to do a fresh install? I only have a hard drive and windows 7 ISO file.

Comment: Do you have a large flash drive?

Comment: yes. but how can i copy windows 7 OS files to the flash drive? just copy all files? does that work?

Comment: You can't just copy all files: I know that. I don't how to make it bootable though (it is of course possible) so just wait for a newer answer.

Comment: See [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive) if you want to use a USB drive, or [installation - Install Windows 7 from ISO image - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/154109/install-windows-7-from-iso-image) for booting from the hard disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a USB port?  Can you boot off of it? Have a 4GB flash drive handy? How about a system you can prepare the flash drive on with .NET Framework 2.0 or higher?  If so, you probably want the [Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe).  You might find [this tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars) handy.

**Update**:  Fixed links.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a host PC running Windows 7 or Vista you can make the USB key bootable using DISKPART. I wrote up some fairly detailed instructions [on my website](http://home4film.com/questions/748/how-can-i-watch-silverlight-based-services-on-an-acer-revo-with-ubuntu/749#749) to install Windows 7 on an Acer Revo.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is post 2000, you can boot from a USB flash drive (you may have to set boot order in the BIOS).

Comment: just copy all files from the ISO? will that work?

Comment: @LaRs: you will need to do more than copy it all to the USB. See other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I did the same thing a couple of weeks back. You don't need any flash drives or any other and is just sufficient with what you have(iso file & hard drive). Just extract the 'iso' file into a folder and run the 'setup' file. After running, you'll get a few windows asking on which drive to install, which would look familiar if you had installed any OS earlier. Assuming that you have installed your your current OS in C:\ , select the same. It may restart couple of times during the process. Done! Finally the earlier version of your OS will be in 'C:\Old Files', which you can 'shift delete' it. And post installation, you can use the same Windows Vista Drivers for Windows 7.

Comment: this will only work if you have already any windows version installed. It will not work if you want a fresh installation.