# Installing Win 7 without a DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb, dvd, bootable-media

I've got the same end goal as [this like named question](https://superuser.com/questions/138056/install-windows-7-without-a-dvd-drive) but a different starting point.

I have a Win7 Ultimate DVD (not an ISO), one XP box with a DVD drive and less than 4GB of free disk, an  XP netbook with no DVD drive, a blank HDD I plan to install on, and a strong aversion to installing any more software on either.

The direction from the sited question (and [others how-to](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/)s I have [found](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool)):

- start with "install something" or
- require the win 7 version of diskpart or
- assume the system is already bootable.

Only the first of those isn't a killer for me but I'd *really* like to avoid it.

*Any Ideas?*

Also, anyone have an idea on how I can make XP treat a DVD drive as an ISO without having to copy it to disk? I know how I can make an ISO within my constraints (Linux live CD, dd, netcat, yuck) but it's going to be a pain.

---

*Edit:* I also have access to a linux box. Would using the Linux tools do the partitioning and then finishing out on with windows work?

Comment: Doh! I just realized I can save the ISO on the USB drive to transfer it to the second computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough room on the netbook hard drive and it can boot from a USB drive then you can install to it from a USB drive.  Microsoft has posted the instructions here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/installing-windows-7-on-a-netbook

Comment: That link gives three options: I already own the DVD and I don't want to buy another copy so (nix option 1), Option two is the same thing as one of the links I gave (nix 2) and option three requires hardware I don't own (nix 3).

Comment: @BCS: How about make an ISO file from the DVD you currently have and use that ISO to follow to instructions?

Comment: @Andrew Moore: that's what I'm already planing on doing once I figure out how to get around the other reason I'm avoiding option 2: I want to avoid installing stuff. Option 1 needs a non ISO/DVD distro that I don't have and can't get without paying more for.

Comment: You can download copies of the ISO files from here:

http://techpp.com/2009/11/11/download-windows-7-iso-official-direct-download-links/

Just right click/save as the file you need.  It will a long time to download as it is a large file.  Then you can use the utility mentioned to convert it to the files needed to install from a USB.

I did exactly this to install on W7 Home Premium on my netbook.

Comment: I've already got a less painful solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the obvious: what's stopping you from moving the DVD drive to the other machine for the duration of the install?

Comment: The other system is netbook.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what they are using diskpart for, is to make a sufficiently large thumbdrive bootable - in which case you can use the [HP drive format tool](http://www.bay-wolf.com/usbmemstick.htm) instead to make it bootable, then copy over the files to see if it works.

Comment: That tool seems to need to be installed. If I'm going to install stuff I'd rather use the MS tool from here: http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool

Comment: oh, right. There was a portable one that did the same... but i haven't really tested it enough to my liking - http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/04/17/lexar-tool-makes-creating-bootable-usb-flash-drives-easy/