# How to install Windows XP without an optical drive

Tags: windows-xp, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows XP through Pen Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive)

I have a nettop pc that came with Linux; I didn't want Windows 7 and didn't want to pay for an OS license I'm not going to use. Now, I'm contemplating if and **how to install my trusty old XP on that machine which can boot from a suitable USB stick?**

The computer does not have an optical drive, and I don't have an external optical drive either. Since it's a nettop and not a "big" pc **I don't want to open the machine** and replace the physical disk. I want to install XP on the existing hardware. Let's assume for the sake of this question that it's okay to simply format the drive (already backed up etc.).

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/138056/install-windows-7-without-a-dvd-drive/138071#138071) has a solution for Win7 because there appears to be a USB version of the installation media that you can get. To my knowledge, that doesn't exist (legally?) for Windows XP, but that would be exactly what I'm looking for. The legality is not relevant insofar that I have the CD media and license; just no optical drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I found after posting that this question has already been answered:
[Installing Windows XP from USB pen drive](https://superuser.com/questions/63995/installing-windows-xp-through-pen-drive/64038#64038)